# Why are these two pieces of Java code producing 2 different results?

Tags: java, int, long-integer

```
    int secs_per_day = 24 * 60 * 60;

    int LIGHTSPEED = 186000;        // 186,000 mi/sec speed of light

    long miles_traveled = secs_per_day * LIGHTSPEED;

    System.out.println("Miles traveled by light in a day: " + miles_traveled);
```

===================================================================================

```
    long secs_per_day = 24 * 60 * 60;

    long LIGHTSPEED = 186000;       // 186,000 mi/sec speed of light

    long miles_traveled = secs_per_day * LIGHTSPEED;

    System.out.println("Miles traveled by light in a day: " + miles_traveled);
```

Comment: Can you please post the output results you are getting

Comment: The referenced issue doesn’t answer the question: both LIGHTSPEED and secs_per_day are way below the value for an int.

Comment: Hi, Hayes Roach,

Here's the 2 different results:


Miles traveled by light in a day: -1109469184
Miles traveled by light in a day: 16070400000

Comment: The values of secs_per_day and LIGHTSPEED are way below the maximum value for int that's why I'm wondering it yields a wrong answer.